# Cassandra and node single docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, cassandra

I need cassandra:3.11.0 and node/Alpine:10.15.3 docker images to be able to compose them into one and be able to execute node and cqlsh commands within single container.  How can i do this?? I really struggle to find solution ;(

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The Docker philosophy is to run one service in one container.

Comment: So how i would run one service with cassandra execute a command on it then take produced file and use it inside node service

Comment: You could go with a [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Comment: @bellackn yeah that was my first thought.  But I was unable to build the image because the file I wanted from the first stage build (cassandra service) was missing. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to provide the `--network=host` flag to my build command and this solved my issue with running cqlsh command in the first stage docker build